# Bullet reflection (ricochet) not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm creating 2D top-down Shooter. I got the the point where I want my bullets to bounce off the walls.I am using OnCollisionEnter2D and rigidbody2D. Bullets do bounce after wall hit, but they are spinning around their own axis. I tried many ways, but can't get this one working.

That is how it looks in practice:

[image]

Here is my code for bullet, and for ricochet child.

```
public class GunBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public PlayerAvatar ownerPlayerAvatar;
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    public int damage = 15;
    [SerializeField] float bulletSpeed;
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    public void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        rigidbody.velocity = transform.right * BulletSpeed;
    }
}

public class RicochetMode : MonoBehaviour
{

    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;
    GunBullet gunBullet;

    private void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2D = transform.root.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gunBullet = transform.root.GetComponent<GunBullet>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Obstacle"))
        {
            Debug.Log("RICOCHET");
            Vector2 reflectedPosition = Vector3.Reflect(transform.right, collision.contacts[0].normal);
            rigidbody2D.velocity = (reflectedPosition).normalized * gunBullet.BulletSpeed;

            Vector2 dir = rigidbody2D.velocity;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            rigidbody2D.MoveRotation(angle);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the bullet facing correct direction. And I don't want to use unity 2D physics materials.

EDIT.

The problem solution was to set
rigidbody2D.angularVelocity to zero as @trollingchar said.

Comment: They recommend using MoveRotation for small angles only (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.html), which is not the case of bullets reflecting back. You can set the rotation directly.

Comment: I am trying rigidbody.rotate = angle, but this seems to not work.

Comment: `rotation`, not `rotate`. If this doesn't work then try setting `transform.localRotation` or `transform.rotation`.

Comment: Yes ofcourse I meant rotation. These seems to not work aswell, maybe i should mention the bullet's rigidbody is dynamic.

Comment: Maybe they are spinning because of unity internal collision handling that thinks it must alter `angularVelocity` as a result of a collision. What value is in there? (if not zero then set it to zero manually in collision handling)

Comment: Yes, it was this. Thank you very much. I expected this has something to do with default effects of collision affecting gameobject. This solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

MoveRotation adds a delta to the rotation angle. It looks like you instead want to set the resultant direction to be `angle` in which case you would use rigidbody.rotation.

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x)*Mathf.Rad2Deg);
```

alternatively, you could try inverting the X or Y transform depending on whether the X or Y velocity changes after collision.

```
transform.localScale = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * -1, transform.localScale.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code, apply it to bullet which should have rigidbody with gravity 0 and a circle collider 2d

```
 public float speed;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "wall")
        {
            ContactPoint2D point = collision.contacts[0];
            Vector2 newDir = Vector2.zero;
            Vector2 curDire = this.transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up);

            newDir = Vector2.Reflect(curDire, point.normal);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector2.up, newDir);
        }
    }
```